# Oracle: what is the situation to use RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR?

Tags: oracle

We can use **RAISE** to fire an exception. What particular situations do we need to use **RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR**?

Thanks.

Comment: I found a useful link for similar question. http://www.toadworld.com/platforms/oracle/b/weblog/archive/2010/07/14/raise-vs-raise-application-error.aspx

Answer (score 30, accepted):

There are two uses for RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR.  The first is to replace generic Oracle exception messages with our own, more meaningful messages.  The second is to create exception conditions of our own, when Oracle would not throw them.

The following procedure illustrates both usages.  It enforces a business rule that new employees cannot be hired in the future.  It also overrides two Oracle exceptions.  One is DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX, which is thrown by a unique key on `EMP(ENAME)`.  The other is a a user-defined exception thrown when the foreign key between `EMP(MGR)` and `EMP(EMPNO)` is violated (because a manager must be an existing employee).

```
create or replace procedure new_emp
    ( p_name in emp.ename%type
      , p_sal in emp.sal%type
      , p_job in emp.job%type
      , p_dept in emp.deptno%type
      , p_mgr in emp.mgr%type 
      , p_hired in emp.hiredate%type := sysdate )
is
    invalid_manager exception;
    PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(invalid_manager, -2291);
    dummy varchar2(1);
begin
    -- check hiredate is valid
    if trunc(p_hired) > trunc(sysdate) 
    then
        raise_application_error
            (-20000
             , 'NEW_EMP::hiredate cannot be in the future'); 
    end if;

    insert into emp
        ( ename
          , sal
          , job
          , deptno
          , mgr 
          , hiredate )
    values      
        ( p_name
          , p_sal
          , p_job
          , p_dept
          , p_mgr 
          , trunc(p_hired) );
exception
    when dup_val_on_index then
        raise_application_error
            (-20001
             , 'NEW_EMP::employee called '||p_name||' already exists'
             , true); 
    when invalid_manager then
        raise_application_error
            (-20002
             , 'NEW_EMP::'||p_mgr ||' is not a valid manager'); 

end;
/
```

How it looks:

```
SQL> exec new_emp ('DUGGAN', 2500, 'SALES', 10, 7782, sysdate+1)
BEGIN new_emp ('DUGGAN', 2500, 'SALES', 10, 7782, sysdate+1); END;

*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-20000: NEW_EMP::hiredate cannot be in the future
ORA-06512: at "APC.NEW_EMP", line 16
ORA-06512: at line 1

SQL>
SQL> exec new_emp ('DUGGAN', 2500, 'SALES', 10, 8888, sysdate)
BEGIN new_emp ('DUGGAN', 2500, 'SALES', 10, 8888, sysdate); END;

*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-20002: NEW_EMP::8888 is not a valid manager
ORA-06512: at "APC.NEW_EMP", line 42
ORA-06512: at line 1


SQL>
SQL> exec new_emp ('DUGGAN', 2500, 'SALES', 10, 7782, sysdate)

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
SQL> exec new_emp ('DUGGAN', 2500, 'SALES', 10, 7782, sysdate)
BEGIN new_emp ('DUGGAN', 2500, 'SALES', 10, 7782, sysdate); END;

*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-20001: NEW_EMP::employee called DUGGAN already exists
ORA-06512: at "APC.NEW_EMP", line 37
ORA-00001: unique constraint (APC.EMP_UK) violated
ORA-06512: at line 1
```

Note the different output from the two calls to RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR in the EXCEPTIONS block.  Setting the optional third argument to TRUE means RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR includes the triggering exception in the stack, which can be useful for diagnosis.

There is more useful information in [the PL/SQL User's Guide](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/errors.htm#i3329).

Answer (score 9):

You use `RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR` in order to create an Oracle style exception/error that is specific to your code/needs.  Good use of these help to produce code that is clearer, more maintainable, and easier to debug.

For example, if I have an application calling a stored procedure that adds a user and that user already exists, you'll usually get back an error like:

```
ORA-00001: unique constraint (USERS.PK_USER_KEY) violated
```

Obviously this error and associated message are not unique to the task you were trying to do.  Creating your own Oracle application errors allow you to be clearer on the intent of the action and the cause of the issue.

```
raise_application_error(-20101, 'User ' || in_user || ' already exists!');
```

Now your application code can write an exception handler in order to process this specific error condition.  Think of it as a way to make Oracle communicate error conditions that your application expects in a "language" (for lack of a better term) that you have defined and is more meaningful to your application's problem domain.

Note that user defined errors must be in the range between -20000 and -20999.

The following [link](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a96624/07_errs.htm#784) provides lots of good information on this topic and Oracle exceptions in general.

Answer (score 4):

Just to elaborate a bit more on Henry's answer, you can also use specific error codes, from raise_application_error and handle them accordingly on the client side.  For example:

Suppose you had a PL/SQL procedure like this to check for the existence of a location record:

```
   PROCEDURE chk_location_exists
   (
      p_location_id IN location.gie_location_id%TYPE
   )
   AS
      l_cnt INTEGER := 0;
   BEGIN
      SELECT COUNT(*)
        INTO l_cnt
        FROM location
       WHERE gie_location_id = p_location_id;

       IF l_cnt = 0
       THEN
          raise_application_error(
             gc_entity_not_found,
             'The associated location record could not be found.');
       END IF;
   END;
```

The raise_application_error allows you to raise a specific error code. In your package header, you can define:
    `gc_entity_not_found INTEGER := -20001;`

If you need other error codes for other types of errors, you can define other error codes using -20002, -20003, etc.

Then on the client side, you can do something like this (this example is for C#):

```
/// <summary>
/// <para>Represents Oracle error number when entity is not found in database.</para>
/// </summary>
private const int OraEntityNotFoundInDB = 20001;
```

And you can execute your code in a try/catch

```
try
{
   // call the chk_location_exists SP
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    if ((e is OracleException) && (((OracleException)e).Number == OraEntityNotFoundInDB))
    {
        // create an EntityNotFoundException with message indicating that entity was not found in
        // database; use the message of the OracleException, which will indicate the table corresponding
        // to the entity which wasn't found and also the exact line in the PL/SQL code where the application
        // error was raised
        return new EntityNotFoundException(
            "A required entity was not found in the database: " + e.Message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if your application accepts errors raise from Oracle, then you can use it. we have an application, each time when an error happens, we call raise_application_error, the application will popup a red box to show the error message we provide through this method.

When using dotnet code, I just use "raise", dotnet exception mechanisim will automatically capture the error passed by Oracle ODP and shown inside my catch exception code.