# Having some confusion in exception types

Tags: oracle, plsql

1. We can pass error message, error code to front end using USER_DEFINED EXCEPTION or PREDEFINED EXCEPTION (others, SQLERRM, SQLCODE) using OUT PARAMETER MODE, then why we use RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR procedure?
2. What is the difference between `RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR` and pragma `EXCEPTION_INIT`?

I have Googled these questions, but can't get a clear answer - that is why posted here.

Answer (score 1):

A user-defined exception doesn't provide any message to the calling application. It'll just get a generic 'ORA-06510: PL/SQL: unhandled user-defined exception'. `raise_application_error` lets you pass a message describing the actual problem.

```
declare
    out_of_stock exception;
begin
    raise out_of_stock;
end;
/

ERROR at line 1:
ORA-06510: PL/SQL: unhandled user-defined exception
ORA-06512: at line 4


begin
    raise_application_error(-20000, 'Cheese is out of stock');
end;
/

ERROR at line 1:
ORA-20000: Cheese is out of stock
ORA-06512: at line 2
```

`pragma exception_init(exception_name, error_code)` lets you associate your own user-defined exception with a system error code. This can be useful from a programming perspective, but ultimately it doesn't add any value for the caller:

```
declare
    invalid_day_of_month exception;
    pragma exception_init(invalid_day_of_month, -1847);

    d date;
begin
    d := to_date('99-JAN-2020','DD-MON-YYYY');
exception
    -- Pointless exception handler - just to demo raising a user-defined exception
    when invalid_day_of_month then raise;
end;
/

ERROR at line 2:
ORA-01847: day of month must be between 1 and last day of month
ORA-06512: at line 10
ORA-06512: at line 7
```

Passing success/failure status via OUT parameters is usually a bad idea because the procedure will appear to have completed successfully, and the caller has to read the status to see whether it really succeeded or not.

Answer (score 1):

[See this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1760596/oracle-what-is-the-situation-to-use-raise-application-error/1761447). The answer to both of those is that `RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR` is the canonical way to define custom error messages to be displayed in the client application. Yes, you could also pass custom messages back using an OUT parameter, or DBMS_OUTPUT, or something similar, but those are not standardized - you'll have to add code on both the server and client side to handle them.

```
DECLARE
   my_exception EXCEPTION;
   PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(my_exception, -20001);
BEGIN
   raise my_exception; -- message is default "ORA-20001: "
END;
/

BEGIN
   raise_application_error(-20001, 'My custom error message'); -- message is "ORA-20001: My custom error message"
END;
/
```

This is often useful when you want to give a more helpful, descriptive error message.

```
DECLARE
  age NUMBER;
BEGIN
  age := 'hello';
EXCEPTION when VALUE_ERROR then
  raise_application_error(-20001, 'Age must be a number.');
END;
/
```

So instead of a generic "PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character to number conversion error", we can tell the user exactly what the problem is: "Age must be a number".