# Oracle exception handling for .NET application

Tags: .net, oracle, plsql

Below is my code snippet from a Oracle stored procedure which inserts into a table "A" from table "B", I have created a nested block (as I would have more insert statements later, so wanted to maintain some modularity). I have exception block with the generic handler "others" for catching the errors, and within that I have an autonomous procedure log_errors_SP which I am using to log errors. I have used raise_application_error within the exception block to notify the invoker of this procedure(.NET code) about exceptions else update the log table with completion status (the last update statement in the code). I need to understand:-

1. if this the correct way to program as for some reason when the procedure is executed from .NET code the log_errors_sp is not executed.
2. log_errors_sp is executed fine when I run my parent stored procedure manually from Oracle developer (so no issues with log_errors_sp).
3. Is it because the error is being trapped on .NET side by it's try catch block rather than the stored procedure's exception block ?.
4. if point 2 is valid how can I change the stored procedure to have the log_errors_SP invoked ?.

```
create or replace procedure some_sp (P_JSON CLOB) is
BEGIN
    do  the basic IN parameter check here..

--nested block to insert data
BEGIN
    insert into A
    (
        CREATED_DT,
        CREATEDBY,
        LASTUPDATED_DT,
        LASTUPDATEDBY
    )
        select sysdate,'SMICLOAD',sysdate,' '
            from b where <conditions>;
                
    EXCEPTION
            WHEN OTHERS THEN
            ov_err_code := 'Table Fail: '||SQLERRM;
            log_errors_SP (p_id,ov_err_code);
            raise_application_error(-20101, 'A:Unable to Insert into the table');
        
    END;
     
    
     UPDATE p_prcs_log 
        set
        COMPLETION_TS=sysdate,
        STATUS='C',
        ERR_MSG='NONE'
        where prcs_id=p_id;
  

END
```

Comment: The way I see it, LOG_ERRORS_SP should be an autonomous transaction procedure which COMMITs at the end. Is that so? If not, make it.

Comment: Yes it is and there is a commit in place.

Comment: Hm, I'd then say that it *should* work as expected. I don't know .NET, but - everything happens within this stored procedure, whether "good" (insert works) or "bad" (insert fails and raises an exception). If it fails, then LOG_ERRORS_SP (the way it is created) should insert a row into the log table and commit it, so you (and anyone else; not just your own session) should be able to see it. Hm again. Strange.

Comment: @Littlefoot as matter of fact i did another test with the .NET developer by moving the log_errors_SP outside the exception block to check if it was executed during a good run and it did execute, so its some mixup of exceptions with oracle and .NET causing the issue

Comment: I can't comment on that; as I said, I don't know .NET. I hope someone else will be able to assist. Good luck!

Comment: Nothing the client application can do will affect how the procedure execution flow of the stored procedure.  If `log_errors_sp` is working correctly and it isn't being executed when the .Net application calls it, then your `insert` statement must not be throwing an error when the stored procedure is called from .Net.  Why do you expect the `insert` statement to fail?

Comment: .NET shouldn't cause any of the interaction problems you describe: it shouldn't matter where you are calling the stored procedure from, nor from which language, nor what error-handling you are doing in this language.  Are you sure you are passing in values that will cause the logging procedure you describe to be invoked?  Is the failure actually happening elsewhere in the stored procedure, where logging isn't being done?

Comment: @LukeWoodward the error created was intentional, meaning I knew which block should error out just for testing prupose, also in my description i have clarified that when run manually the logging procedure works fine.

Comment: @JustinCave the insert statement is supposed to parse a JSON and insert into table, and it is better to have exception handling to check errors ?

Comment: @JustinCave just to add, the .NET developer is able to see the oracle exception when the insert failed, in his try catch block.

Comment: @DevenderKumar - Are you sure that the .NET developer is seeing the error from this particular line?  If the `insert` statement into A fails, PL/SQL enters the exception handler and calls `log_errors_sp`.  If `log_errors_sp` is an autonomous transaction that makes a change and commits it, that change will be committed before the `raise_application_error` call is made.  So it will be committed before the .Net application is notified of the error.  Plus, Oracle has no idea what the client application is going to do with error handling.  Something in your description appears to be off.

Comment: Can you post a self-contained test case that reproduces the problem?

Comment: @JustinCave from the testing done today with .NET developer, the observations were: 1. when the log_errors_sp was moved out of exception block of procedure it executed fine from .NET, 2. when it was moved back it didn't execute as i didn't see the changes in my log table, 3. another observation to prove the same was the rollback being executed from .NET code during an error, the entire insert was rolled back, so if log_errors_sp did commit then the log table should have had the needed entries, but there weren't any.

Comment: @JustinCave, oracle need not know what client is doing with the errors, as long as the invoker commits or rolls back the transaction and closes the connection at all times after the transaction. I will try to produce a self-contained test case for this.

Comment: @DevenderKumar - Right.  But my point is that since Oracle has no idea how or whether the caller is going to handle an exception, there is no way that .NET code could influence whether the PL/SQL exception block is entered, whether the `log_errors_sp` call is made, or whether the autonomous transaction in that stored procedure makes and commits a change.

Comment: thanks @JustinCave i will try to gather additional information based on additional de-bugging. I may be wrong in understanding .NET's behavior, but from plsql standpoint do you think my code snippet is following the correct process ?

Comment: @DevenderKumar - It looks reasonable.  Unless the error message you're going to rethrow is going to add a lot of value and context, though, I'd generally prefer to simply re-raise the error you caught rather than catching a new one.  I'd probably want to log the call stack and error stack rather than just the error message.  And I'm not sure how many of these exception handlers you're expecting to have in a single procedure.  I'd prefer just one unless there is business value in providing different exceptions for each statement in the procedure.

Comment: @JustinCave ok, so you think the "raise" statement with a user defined exception is a better choice over raise_application_error ?, are there any drawbacks in having exception handling within individual nested blocks ? over having one exception block for entire procedure ?

Comment: @DevenderKumar - It's a question of whether the custom exception adds some business value.  If you're providing an error message that adds some context that the Oracle error message and error stack don't have, it makes sense to have a custom exception.  The message "unable to insert into table" doesn't tell you anything that the existing error stack doesn't so I wouldn't consider that adding value.  Since your `raise_application_error` isn't including the existing error stack, you're throwing away more information than you're including.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1760596/oracle-what-is-the-situation-to-use-raise-application-error is a good discussion

Comment: @JustinCave agree i have a very generic message, but the actual oracle SLERRM is stored in the log_errors_sp, which logs it in the log table, the article your provided is very informative will analyze based on it. Is there anything i need to have my .NET developer check on his side for this issue ?

Comment: @DevenderKumar - But the SQLERRM is often not nearly as useful as the actual error and call stack.  Nothing in the .NET code can impact how a stored procedure handles exceptions.  If the procedure is behaving differently for different callers, I'd strongly suspect the issue is that the callers are passing in different parameters which cause the procedure to behave differently.

Comment: thanks @JustinCave will gather more information on this.

Comment: @JustinCave so what i did was replace the raise_application_error with return statement and execute the log_errors_sp within a IF condition based on the SQLCODE in the exception block, so now the commit and rollback is happening properly within .NET and the autonomous transaction log_errors_sp is also executing without any issues.